# Getting a menu to loop when invalid choice is made BASH

Tags: bash, scripting, menu, case

Hey guys so I am trying to get this menu to loop whenever an invalid choice is made in a case statement but having a hard time figuring out what I should be calling back to in my while loop I tried using * as that is whats referenced in case as the invalid choice but it expects an operand when it sees that so I am not sure how to call it back below is the code any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#Main menu.
#Displays a greeting and waits 8 seconds before clearing the screen

echo "Hello and welcome to the group 97 project we hope you enjoy using our program!"

sleep 8s
clear

while [[ $option -eq "*" ]]
do
    #Displays a list of options for the user to choose.

    echo "Please select one of the folowing options."
    echo -e "\t0. Exit program"
    echo -e "\t1. Find the even multiples of any number."
    echo -e "\t2. Find the terms of any linear sequence given the rule Un=an+b."
    echo -e "\t2. Find the numbers that can be expressed as the product of two nonnegative integers in succession and print  them in increasing order."

    #Reads the option selection from user and checks it against case for what to do.

    read -n 1 option

    case $option in
        0)
            exit ;;
        1)
            echo task1 ;;
        2)
            echo task2 ;;
        3)
            echo task3 ;;
        *)
            clear
            echo "Invalid selection, please try again.";;
    esac
done
```

Comment: fwiw, a good habit to get into, from an ease of readability perspective, is to indent code and use some blank lines to break up a wall of text ...

Comment: ok thanks for the tip ill try to start doing that from now on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `select` implementation of your menu:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PS3='Please select one of the options: '
select _ in \
  'Exit program' \
  'Find the even multiples of any number.' \
  'Find the terms of any linear sequence given the rule Un=an+b.' \
  'Find the numbers that can be expressed as the product of two nonnegative integers in succession and print them in increasing order.'
do
  case $REPLY in
    1) exit ;;
    2) echo task1 ;;
    3) echo task2 ;;
    4) echo task3 ;;
    *) echo 'Invalid selection, please try again.' ;;
  esac
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't reinvent the builtin [`select`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-select)
command

```sh
choices=(
    "Exit program"
    "Find the even multiples of any number."
    "Find the terms of any linear sequence given the rule Un=an+b."
    "Find the numbers that can be expressed as the product of two nonnegative integers in succession and print  them in increasing order."
)

PS3="Please select one of the options: "
select choice in "${choices[@]}"; do
    case $choice in
        "${choices[0]}") exit ;;
        "${choices[1]}")
            echo task1
            break ;;
        "${choices[2]}")
            echo task2
            break ;;
        "${choices[3]}")
            echo task3
            break ;;
    esac
done
```

If you want to stay in the menu until "Exit" then remove the breaks.